# What is the name of this part to a 2005 Scion xb

Tags: battery, scion

What is the name of this part? It hooks on my battery:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Looks like some sort of high output electrical distribution / fuse box.  Its pretty important to the operation of your vehicle.  Its also dangerous if that thing is loose and flopping around.